# Linux RAID0 creation with existing data disk and an empty disk

Tags: linux, centos7, raid0

I have a CentOS 7.7 server which has a vhd `/dev/sdc` mounted (format-type= btrfs); it contains data.

I attached a empty vhd to the VM, `/dev/sdd` (I didn't partition this disk using `fdisk`)

`lsblk` command lists the attached disk but no mount point.

used, 
`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level 0 --raid-devices=2 --name=/data-disk  /dev/sdc /dev/sdd`

**Output:**

> mdadm: cannot open /dev/sdc: Device or resource busy

**Question:**

- Will the data from the disk `/dev/sdc` get wiped out when I try to create a RAID0 array?
- I can issue `umount /dev/sdc` and issue the `mdadm --create` command, but is that a proper approach to do this.

=== in case of successful RAID0 creation ===

Below command would be executed:

```
mkfs.btrfs /dev/md0
```

Editing the /etc/fstab, with the uuid info

===

Trying to add two disks to RAID0, one is already setup as backup, which has data. The new one is attached, could see the disk using `lsblk`, but

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc      8:32   0    100G  0 disk /cass_backup
sdd      8:48   0    100G  0 disk
```

`df -h`

```
/dev/sdc        100G  82G  20G  20% /data_disk
```

How does the distribution of data between mounted and unmounted disk done? 
Do I need to mount the new one (/dev/sdd) first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforming a single disk to a RAID0 array will **break** your filesystem. More precisely you would first need to carefully distribute the data of `/dev/sdc` onto both disks.

You can create a RAID1 array more easily, since RAID1 has identical data on both disks: cf. [Converting a single drive system to RAID](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_a_single_drive_system_to_RAID).

Fortunately you are using **btrfs**, which combines the power of a filesystem, RAID and LVM. So [add the second disk to your btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Conversion) and convert it to a RAID0 array.

**Edit**: In your case the conversion to RAID0 is as simple as: mounting your original btrfs filesystem (let say on `/mnt`). Expand the filesystem:

```
mount /dev/sdc /mnt
btrfs device add /dev/sdd /mnt
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid0 -mconvert=raid0 /mnt
```

The data on `/dev/sdd` will be lost, but data from `/dev/sdc` will remain.

Comment: Trying to add two disks to RAID0, one is already setup as backup, which has data. The new one is attached, could see the disk using lsblk, but 

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc      8:32   0    100G  0 disk /cass_backup
sdd      8:48   0    100G  0 disk

df -h 
/dev/sdc        100G  82G  20G  20% /data_disk

How does the distribution of data between mounted and unmounted disk done? Do i need to mount the new one (/dev/sdd) first?

Comment: I added more info to the answer.